# Extract consecutive sequences from vector

Tags: r, sequence

I have a vector called v with positive and negative values as well as zeros. The question is, how to extract (in a list) all the continuous sequences of positive numbers, that is the sequences of positive numbers separated by zeros.

Here is v:

```
v <- c(-75.09619, -38.31229,   0,  57.17792,  65.55923, 108.52735, 104.29929,  32.47125,0,   0,   0,   0, -26.65008, -49.48638, -79.60670,-90.55343, -34.60761,   0, 21.48842, 38.83820, 42.28727, 0)
```

The output must be something like:

```
[1] 57.17792,  65.55923, 108.52735, 104.29929,  32.47125
[2] 21.48842 , 38.83820, 42.28727
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, without the list requirement this is probably trivial. With the list requirement, you'll probably end up using `rle` and a loop of some sort.

Comment: It was just to illustrate the desired output (a list of vectors)

Comment: you should not let others do your homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
indices <- which(v[v>=0]==0)
x <- Map(function(x,y) setdiff(v[v>=0][(y+1):(x-1)],0),
         indices[2:length(indices)],
         indices[1:(length(indices)-1)])
x[vapply(x,length,1L)>0]
#[[1]]
#[1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125
#[[2]]
#[1] 21.48842 38.83820 42.28727
```

What I did:

- took the 0 position out of the vector formed with the >=0 values of `v`
- with the `Map` function, you can extract the part of the vector  between two zeros
- the last line's purpose is to strip from the result the sequences without values (if for instance there are sequences of two or more zeroes in the original vector)

Comment: `Map` is `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` - might save you a couple of characters here.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a short one using `split`:

```
split(v[v>0],cumsum(v==0)[v>0])
#$`1`
#[1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125
#
#$`6`
#[1] 21.48842 38.83820 42.28727
```

This essentially just subsets `v` to positive numbers, then uses the `cumsum(v==0)` counter (which will be stable within a group of positive values, and increase when it hits the immediately following `0`), to `split` this group. Voila!

---

Another attempt using `rle`:

```
r <- rle(v>0)
start <- cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values] - r$lengths[r$values] + 1
end <- start + r$lengths[r$values] - 1
Map(function(start,end) v[start:end],start,end)

#[[1]]
#[1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 21.48842 38.83820 42.28727
```

Comment: Oh, good, an `rle` solution. Now I can rest easily. Now we need one with paste, gregexpr, regmatches ;-)

Comment: This `split(v[v>0],cumsum(v==0)[v>0])` meets my requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here one option :

```
ll <- split(v,cumsum(v==0))                      ## split data by 0 jump
ll <- lapply(ll,function(x){                     ## for each group 
  x <- x[x!=0]                                   ## remove null values   
  if(all(x>0) && length(x)>0)x else NA      ## check if all values are postifs
})
ll[!is.na(ll)]

# $`1`
# [1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125
# 
# $`6`
# [1] 21.48842 38.83820 42.28727
```

The idea:

1. create a group identifier for each 0
2. For each group remove 0, check if all values are positifs , otherwise returns NA
3. remove missing vectors from from the final result.

### data.table solution

It is better to group results in a data.table(data.frame) than in a list. I used the same code above just I wrap it in a data.table structure.

```
library(data.table)
A=data.table(v=v)
A[,{x <- v[v!=0]
    if(all(x>0) && length(x)>0)x else NA_real_},
    cumsum(v==0)][!is.na(V1)]

#     cumsum        V1
# 1:      1  57.17792
# 2:      1  65.55923
# 3:      1 108.52735
# 4:      1 104.29929
# 5:      1  32.47125
# 6:      6  21.48842
# 7:      6  38.83820
# 8:      6  42.28727
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw one in

```
v <- c(-75.09619, -38.31229,   0,  57.17792,  65.55923, 108.52735, 104.29929,  32.47125,0,   0,   0,   0, -26.65008, -49.48638, -79.60670,-90.55343, -34.60761,   0,21.48842, 38.83820, 42.28727, 0)


r <- rle(v > 0)
r <- r$lengths[r$values]

(pos <- v[v > 0])
# [1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125  21.48842  38.83820  42.28727



lapply(r, function(x) {
  out <- pos[1:x]
  pos <<- pos[-(1:x)]
  out
})

# [[1]]
# [1]  57.17792  65.55923 108.52735 104.29929  32.47125
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 21.48842 38.83820 42.28727
```